# rdata & ggplot: specifying plot initial plot size?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggplot2` and attempting to create an empty plot with some basic dimensions, like I might do w/ the stock `plot` function like so:

```
plot(x = c(0, 10), y=c(-7, 7))
```

Then I'd plot the points with `geom_point()` (or, stock `point()` function)

How can I set that basic plot up using ggplot? I'm only able to draw a plot using like:

```
ggplot() + layer(data=data, mapping = aes(x=side, y=height), geom = "point")
```

But this has max x/y values based on the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this:

Basically the same approach as with base graphics; the first layer put down has the limits you want, using `geom_blank()`

```
ggplot() +
  geom_blank(data=data.frame(x=c(0,10),y=c(-7,7)), mapping=aes(x=x,y=y))
```

Using `expand_limits()`

```
ggplot() +
  expand_limits(x=c(0,10), y=c(-7,7))
```

In both cases, if your data extends beyond this, the axes will be further expanded.

Comment: The difference between these approaches and @joran's is that this will ensure the axes cover _at least_ the specified range (and more if the data warrant); using `xlim`, etc. set the axes to _exactly_ that range (dropping data outside that range); using `coord_cartesian` sets the axes to _exactly_ that range, just not showing anything outside of it (the distinction is noticeable with summaries, but not necessarily points).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the overall plotting region limits using `xlim` and `ylim`:

```
ggplot(data = data) + 
    geom_point(aes(x = side, y = height) + 
    xlim(c(0,10)) + 
    ylim(c(-7,7))
```

Also see `coord_cartesian` which *zooms* in and out rather than hard coding the axis limits.

*Edit* Since @Brian clarified the differences between his answer and mine well, I thought I should mention it as well in my answer, so no one misses it. Using `xlim` and `ylim` will set the limits of the plotting region *no matter what* data you add in subsequent layers. Brian's method using `expand_limits` is a way to set the *minimum* ranges.

Comment: Would this blow up if there were some NA values in height and side? Seeing: mapping: x = side, y = height ; geom_point: na.rm = FALSE ; stat_identity:  ; position_identity: (width = NULL, height = NULL)

Comment: @Wells Not entirely sure what you mean. `ggplot` omits NA values in the data by default.